# SqlDataReader result view returns notdefined somthing

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a little problem with my code.

I try to retrieve data from local SQL Server. The connection is right, and so is the stored procedure. But when I read rows from the `SqlDataReader`, it is empty. But when I watch the `SqlDataReader`, there is something with ? inside, but is not the result.

The SQL query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is my code:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-U8E1S5I;Database=Queue;Trusted_Connection=true";
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", conn);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer
                          {
                            Name = (string)reader["CustomerName"],
                            WaitingNumber = (int?)reader["CustomerNumber"],
                            EnterTime = (DateTime?)reader["CustomerNumber"],
                            Status = (int)reader["CustomerStatus"]
                          });                        
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is "Enumeration Yielded No Results" with two rows that contains ?: (break point is before the reader.read())

[Enumeration Yielded No Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ieUQ.png)

Thank for help.

Comment: It is a bad idea to try to iterate a `reader` - apart from anything else, when you do that, you've consumed the data; essentially: even *looking* in the debugger at this *can destroy the value*. So; what happens currently **without the breakpoint**; do you get as far as `reader.Read()`? does it go into the inside to get as far as `customers.Add` ? Note: strictly speaking it would be a good idea to set `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` here, but you'll often get away with it, as long as you aren't passing parameters

Comment: Typo: you're using `CustomerNumber` twice. It's probably not both an `int` and `DateTime`. (This is unrelated to your original error, but it's the next thing you'll run into.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually, I strongly suspect that you're "right on the money" here, and that the *real* problem is an invalid cast exception when reading `EnterTime` - I further suspect OP is trying to debug the code to find out why that isn't working, and is accidentally consuming the data via the debug breakpoint  view

Comment: @jeroen it was the next thing, but primary I didn't put the command type, so result was simply empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `SqlCommand` has the property [`CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) defined as `CommandType.Text` which is used by ad-hoc `sql`. You have to specify you are using `stored procedure` by setting `CommandType` on your command. For sample:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Do not forget to add the namespace `System.Data`.

Comment: while I agree with you that this should be specified: the fact that it didn't throw an exception means that this probably isn't the **immediate** problem

Comment: Thank for the comment @MarcGravell. I would like to ask why did you say (in a comment on the question) that iterate over the `SqlDataReader` is a bad idea? I know it is still connected on the database but is there any other good approch to keep the performance when getting data from a result set? Thank you.

Comment: I mean specifically *in the debugger* it is a bad idea, since it irreversibly changes the data; since the IDE expands to the end of a sequence, this means that once you've looked at it once in the IDE, the data is no longer there

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you're using a stored procedure, see below

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Or

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", conn) {
   CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
```

Comment: while I agree with you that this should be specified: the fact that it didn't throw an exception means that this probably isn't the **immediate** problem